# Will Remote Access Trojans work on an offline PC?

Tags: malware, rat

Using a USB memory stick that was frequently used on a Trojan-infected PC on an uninfected offline Windows 10 PC. Physically, the PC has no wireless adapter, so it cannot be connected to wifi. Bluetooth is present but disabled in the device manager.

Is it possible to prevent remote-control malware infections such as Trojan horses?

Comment: "Prevent infections"? No. but will a RAT work without a network? No. Can non-RAT malware cause damage? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just employ logic.

> Using a USB memory that was frequently used on a Trojan-infected PC on an uninfected offline PC

Obviously connecting an infected USB stick to a clean device may result in that device becoming infected. Whether or not it is offline does not really matter here.

> remote control malware

Your offline PC is infected. This is not your PC any longer. However, the PC is offline, so the malware cannot receive instructions from its owners over the network. It may, however, have already come with its own set of instructions, in which case it will do whatever it was programmed to do.

Unless...

> bluetooth is present but disabled in the device manager)

Then the malware re-enables bluetooth and might listen to further instructions over bluetooth, however this obviously requires that whatever is sending these instructions must be in close proximity to your PC.

Comment: I was thinking about an APT scenario where the offline PC had the keys for a Bitcoin wallet the Lazarus Group was after. Even in that case they would not be using an infected USB stick, as it would be more efficient to just access the PC physically or even steal the entire computer.

Comment: gaazkam,I can't explain the situation here,but a APT hacker are a relative.There is only one culprit. We don't live in the same place. even if I insert a USB and get infected, can I assume that the RAT can no longer be used by removing the bluetooth adapter from the PC and never using that USB again?

Comment: gaazkam,If I physically remove bluetooth module, does that mean remote control is not possible even if the RAT is infected?

Comment: @john-trmb Like I said in my answer: if your PC is completely disconnected from anything then the attacker cannot (obviously) send any further commands to the malware they have installed on your PC, however, the malware may have already came bundled with previously prepared instructions, in which case it will be able to wreak havoc on your offline PC according to these previously prepared instructions.

Comment: @john-trmb Also note that there may be safe(ish) ways to connect an infected USB stick to your PC, (hopefully) avoiding infection, if you have some technical skills. This is never 100% fail-safe though, and depending on the skills and determination of the attacker you may still get infected. (Or, alternatively, the bad USB may shock your PC with an electric discharche, trashing it)